# Can supplements inhibit production of human synthesized molecules?

Tags: muscle, testosterone, creatine

In the field of bodybuilding, various substances such as, growth hormone, testosterone, creatine and amino acids are naturally synthesized by the human body, nevertheless increasing quantities of those substances by supplements does increase the muscles related performances.
My understanding is that when those supplements are taken, the body adapts by producing less of the natural substance and minimizing the "channels" that bring the substance on site.

My question is, what happens when we do this long enough and then stop. Is there a risk that the natural production would not get back up to normal, thus making us dependent on supplements ? I've read that it is indeed the case for testosterone aka steroids, but not for creatine, I'd like to know why the difference.

Comment: This is not a physical fitness question hence the absence of answer. Whoever migrated it from medical sciences without my consent is incompetent. I as the author believe it is a biology question.